# How to use custom id serializer with Jackson?

Tags: serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.1.4 and want to serialize collections of objects that extend an Event class, and where the JSON has to include the class name for polymorphism purposes. I have put a @JsonTypeInfo annotation on Event, but unfortunately I can't use CLASS as strategy, because my object instantiation pattern is "new FooEvent(){{bar=someValue;}}", which will create anonymous inner classes. I want to put in "FooEvent" as the type in JSON, rather than the anonymous inner class.

It seems like what I need is to do this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use= JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
```

But how do I register my own custom id serializer that will output the name of the class?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to solve this: basically add a @JsonTypeIdResolver annotation on the same class as has @JsonTypeInfo, then implement a resolver which it can refer to. [Here's](https://github.com/rickardoberg/stuff/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rickardoberg/cqrs/memory/CustomClassIdResolver.java) what mine looks like. It essentially just removes anonymous inner class if present.

Comment: Hi Rickard! Unfortunately your example is no longer online and while I'm trying to come up with my own version (that extends `TypeIdResolverBase`) I get the exception at runtime that this cannot be instantiated because there is no empty constructor available. Any help would be greatly appreciated!